# Set a empty Text in a form

Tags: javascript, extjs, set

Is it possible to set an emptyText just like I did with a title ?

```
me.myForm.down('#field').setTitle('New Title');

{                            
                            xtype: 'filefield',                                
                            width: 490,                                
                            fieldLabel: 'Buscar Foto',
                            labelWidth: 90,
                            emptyText: 'Text I want to set',
                            buttonText: 'Buscar Foto',                               

                    },
```

emptyText, I want to change it depending on some conditions.

Comment: Throw some html up there so we can see what you're trying to target.

Comment: What do you mean by `emptyText`?

Answer (score 1):

Nope as of ExtJS 6.5.3 Classic. Although the [emptyText](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.File.html#cfg-emptyText) is bindable property. And there is in fact [.setEmptyText(](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.File.html#placeholder-setEmptyText)) method. **It does not work.**

Note the message:

> Overridden to undefined as emptyText is not supported with
>   inputType:'file' and should be avoided. The default text to place into
>   an empty field.

And from my little test, it doesn't work https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2egc
*Also tested with VM bind, not working too.*

Why is the property marked as `bindable`?  Idk probably bug in the docs.

*Modern version of ext doesn't support emptyText at all*

---

As a workaround you could create new fileField element with predefined emptyText and used it based on the if you need. Something like this:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2egd

Comment: It is in the docs because `emptyText` is a property on the parent class, `Ext.form.field.Text`, from which `filefield` derives. One cannot remove properties of the parent class from the child class, and the used docgen, `jsduck`, does not allow to remove documentation 
 of unsupported properties of the parent classes from the documentation of the child classes' documentations either.

Comment: I think you should be able to do it. If you override it in the child and specify `@private` in the docs it should not show up. Either way it's a bug in the docs, if not in ExtJS than in jsduck ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, that works too:

```
var Myfield  = Ext.first('myField');
Myfield.el.dom.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].placeholder = 'MyEmptyText';
```